# hoe to make sum of one sql table column with ignoring duplicate values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
quoteId  price
  1        50
  1        50  
  2        10
  3        40
  3        40
  3        40  
  4        10
```

In this table I always get the same `price` for each `quoteId`.
*Example: `quoteId = 1` has multiple entries with the `price` of 50.*

By using `SUM` I get the total sum of the `price` column which is:
`50 + 50 + 10 + 40 + 40 + 40 + 10 = 240`

However, I only want to sum the unique `price` for `quoteId` which is: 

`50+10+40+10 = 110`

How can I approch this?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: just add group by quoteId, price

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved your problem then accept it as answer; otherwise comment the remaining issue below the answer.

Comment: Please tag properly.  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is DISTINCT

**Example**

```
Select MyTotal = sum(price) 
 from (Select Distinct quoteId,price From YourTable) A
```

**Returns**

```
MyTotal
110
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query will work:

```
select sum(price)
from yourTablename
group by quoteId,price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested query to compute an intermediate value by `quoteId` using `avg` *( or `max` or `min` with your data)*

But you need know why you have duplicate value by quotedId, may be you have a mistake before.

```
select sum(price) from (
  select
    quoteId,
    avg(price) price,
  from
    your_table
  group by
    quoteId
) as x
```

*This query is compliant with ISO standard SQL and will works with several database engine*